# How do I target all items in a list, when a change occurs in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm building a site that uses Vue for to power the majority of the UI. The main component is a list of videos that is updated whenever a certain URL pattern is matched.

The main (`video-list`) component looks largely like this:

```
let VideoList = Vue.component( 'video-list', {
    data: () => ({ singlePost: '' }),
    props: ['posts', 'categorySlug'],
    template: `
        <div>
            <transition-group tag="ul">
                <li v-for="(post, index) in filterPostsByCategory( posts )">
                    <div @click.prevent="showPost( post )">
                        <img :src="post.video_cover" />
                        /* ... */
                    </div>
                </li>
            </transition-group>
        </div>`,
    methods: {
        orderPostsInCategory: function ( inputArray, currentCategory ) {
            let outputArray = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
                let currentCategoryObj = inputArray[i].video_categories.find( (category) => {
                    return category.slug === currentCategory;
                });
                let positionInCategory = currentCategoryObj.category_post_order;
                outputArray[positionInCategory] = inputArray[i];
            }
            return outputArray;
        },
        filterPostsByCategory: function ( posts ) {
            let categorySlug = this.categorySlug,
                filteredPosts = posts.filter( (post) => {
                    return post.video_categories.some( (category) => {
                        return category.slug === categorySlug;
                    })
                });
            return this.orderPostsInCategory( filteredPosts, categorySlug );
        }
    }
});
```

The `filterPostsByCategory()` method does its job switching between the various possible categories, and instantly updating the list, according to the routes below:

```
let router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    linkActiveClass: 'active',
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: VideoList, props: {categorySlug: 'home-page'} },
        { path: '/category/:categorySlug', component: VideoList, props: true }
    ]
});
```

The difficulty I'm having is transitioning the list in the way that I'd like. Ideally, when new category is selected all currently visible list items would fade out and the new list items would then fade in. I've looked at the [vue transitions documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html), but haven't been able to get the effect I'm after.

The issue is that some items have more than one category, and when switching between these categories, those items are never affected by whatever transition I try to apply (I assume because Vue is just trying to be efficient and update as few nodes as possible). It's also possible that two or more categories contain the exact same list items, and in these instances enter and leave methods don't seem to fire at all.

So the question is, what would be a good way to ensure that I can target all current items (regardless of whether they're still be visible after the route change) whenever the route patterns above are matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you noticed the special `key` attribute in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key)?

Vue.js is really focused on performance, because of that, when you modify lists used with `v-for`, vue tries to update as few DOM nodes as possible. Sometimes it only updates text content of the nodes instead of removing the whole node and then append a newly created one. Using `:key` you tell vue that this node is specifically related to the given key/id, and you force vue to completely update the DOM when the list/array is modified and as a result the key is changed. In your case is appropriate to bind the `key` attribute to some info related to the post and the category filter itself, so that whenever the list is modified or the category is changed the whole list may be rerendered and thus apply the animation on all items:

```
<li v-for="(post, index) in filterPostsByCategory( posts )" :key="post.id + categorySlug">
    <div @click.prevent="showPost( post )">
        <img :src="post.video_cover" />
        /* ... */
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: I've omitted a number of directives for brevity's sake. It's also not clear how this answer is meant to address the question.

Comment: @verism You should be able to use `key` to ensure that Vue doesn't retain elements from one list to the next.

Comment: @RoyJ I understand what you're saying, but I already have a key property on each item. CSS transitions are not applied to items that persist across category changes.

Comment: Exactly, vue.js is really focused on performance, because of that, when you modify lists like that, vue tries to update as few DOM nodes as possible. Some times it only updates text content of the nodes instead of removing the hole node and then append a newly created one. Using `:key` you tell vue that this node is specifically related to the given javascript object/item, and you force vue to completely update the DOM when the list/array is modified.

Comment: In particular, your `key` value should have some indication of the filter being applied so that no `key` value carries over from one filter to another.

Comment: @RoyJ That makes much more sense! I've been using a key throughout the project, but it was tied to the database ID of the item. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: **Update**: even with a key value that refers to the item's new render position, the problem still persists.

Comment: @verism Don't use render position. Work the filter name in.

Comment: Indeed! Something like: `:key="post.id + categorySlug"`

Comment: Thanks, now i'm definitely getting somewhere. Can I suggest adding this info to the answer - then I'll be happy to mark it as correct.

Comment: Of`course! I tried to make it more detailed. You are welcome to suggest an edit if you think something is still missing. Also I would suggest you to make use of the computed properties for the filtered array rather then using method ;)